# Non-recursive algorithm for determine all sums possible from set of numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, recursion, set

I'm looking for a non-recursive algorithm (preferably in C#) which will generate a list of all sums possible from a set of positive numbers.

E.g. For a set of three numbers "1,2,3" the following seven sums are possible:

1

2

3

1+2=3

1+3=4

2+3=5

1+2+3=6

The maximum set size would be around 50. I know how to approach this problem recursively, but have been limited by the call stack in the past when tackling a similar problem, so want to avoid it this time.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: In the worst case, there are `2 ^ 50` different sums.  Or are there any additional constraints that reduce their number? By the way, in a recursive version, the call depth is at most `50`. I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: @kraskevich Not just in the worst case. The example in the question shows that different combinations that result in the same sum should be counted separately for each combination, so given `N` numbers, you'll *always* get `2^N` sums.

Comment: that's a good point. there are really only six sums in this particular example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need all possible sums then you can use this function.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetSums(List<int> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
           select
               (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
               where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
               select list[i]).Sum();
}
```

And, then just call it like that:

```
var result = GetSums(myList).ToList();
```

***Additional information***:

You can also use this method for generating combinations[(source)](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
           select
               from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
               where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
               select list[i];
}
```

And find the sums of all combinations with the help of `Sum()` method from the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
var result = GetPowerSet(myList).Select(x => x.Sum()).ToList();
```

Comment: Your first function works great. Thanks!
FYI, I also found that I can remove duplicates easily with 
var result = GetSums(myList).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
I also had to remove the first entry in the list since it was zero.

Comment: @Caustix Glad to help. Yep, but you don't need to call `ToList()` two times. You can use `GetSums(myList).Distinct().ToList();` for getting unique values.

Answer (score 4):

Sums from subsets are in direct correspondence with subsets, which are also in direct correspondence with binary sequences. If you have five items in your set, you want to iterate over all bit sequences from 00000 to 11111. Equivalently, you want to iterate from 0 to 2^5-1. If a bit is set to one, you should include the value in the sum. So, something like this:

```
for i = 0 to 2^n-1
  sum = 0
  for j = 0 to n - 1
    if i & (1 << j) then 
      sum += items[j]
  yield return sum
```

Obviously, this is pseudocode and doesn't deal with values of n larger than the number of bits used by i, but that is going to be a long iteration. This should at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If sum of all numbers is limited by reliable value, then DP solution exists with complexity O(N * MaxSum), else there are O(2^N) possible sums.

DP solution (Delphi):

```
procedure GenerateAllSums(const A: array of Integer);
var
  ASums: array of Boolean;
  S, i, j: Integer;
begin
  //find maximal possible sum
  S := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(A) do
    S := S + A[i];
  //make array for possible sums
  SetLength(ASums, S + 1);
  ASums[0] := True; // all others - false

  for i := 0 to High(A) do
    for j := S - A[i] downto 0 do
      if ASums[j] then
        ASums[j + A[i]] := True;
  //Now 'True' elements of ASums denote possible sum values
end;
```